# how to use published power BI report as image url

Tags: powerbi, dax

Do we have option to use a published power BI report as Image URL for new report? I need to use 3 images(Red, yellow and Green) as values in my report. These images should not be from web.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is now included in the desktop. 1) make sure you download the latest version. 2) adding an image can be done from the toolbar in the PBI Desktop(You can add local image using this tool)

[image]

Just add the image to your desktop file and publish, the report will update on the Service.

Comment: This Image option is fine. I need to use Images as values inside a table cell. That Image should be from server or sharepoint.

Comment: But are the images accessible from the internet?

Comment: Yes.Uploaded image in this tool will be accessible from the internet.

Comment: 419FFEEC41722F21ED05BF15